# Return the value and not #N/A when using IF function to compare

Tags: excel, if-statement, cell

I am trying to return either 1 or 0 when [the two cells are different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpsDV.png) [when using the =IF(F90986=G90986, 1, 0) statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFDfp.png), but because it has #N/A, it's returning #N/A instead.

How can I make it return 0 or 1?

Is it because G90986 is result of a VLOOKUP?

Answer (score 0):

So use iferror():

```
=IF(and(iferror(F90986,True),F90986=G90986), 1, 0))
```

Where if cell F90986 contains #N/A then it won't get completed

BUT you could do the same by using IFNA() which would not automatically assume all other errors...

Answer (score 0):

Consider encasing your formula in an IfError statement, which returns a specified value if your result is an error, otherwise, it returns the value of the formula.

Here's an example:

```
=IfError(IF(F90986=G90986,1,0),0)
```

The second zero is what you would change if you want an error to display something else.

Hope that helps.